# With custom type/providers how can i restrict refreshonly?

Tags: puppet

I have two custom type/providers.  The first creates a resource, and manages a few properties on said resource.  The second is a refreshonly (exec style) type/provider that needs to import some data into the resource.  I need the import to only execute on the initial creation, not when the properties are changed.

Simple example:

```
nifi_processgroup{'processgroup':
  ensure   =>present,
  location =>'0,100',
}
nifi_templateimport{'atemplate':
  processgroup=>'processgroup',
  template    =>'standard-template',
  refreshonly =>true,
  subscribe   =>Nifi_processgroup['processgroup'],
}
```

so if location updates, it refreshes the import.  Is there any way to limit/scope the refresh?

Comment: Your type should have a `refresh` method where you define the logic for invoking the provider's `refresh` method. You can do it there.

Comment: I have a refresh method but it always executes.  Don't know how to limit the emitted refresh or filter the incoming refresh.

Comment: Which `refresh` method is always invoked? The type or the provider? Also, you really should share the code so we can do more than guess and be vague.

Comment: the `nifi_templateimport` type's refresh method is always called whenever the `nifi_processgroup` has any property changes either ensure or properties.

Comment: @ruckc, did you mean to say that `nifi_templateimport`'s refresh method is called *whether or not* the `nifi_processgroup` has any property changes?  Because when the latter does have property changes is exactly when you should expect the former to be refreshed.

Comment: It's called when the processgroup is created or changed.  I want it to only be called when created.

Answer (score 0):

> I need the import to only execute on the initial creation, not when the properties are changed.

Then you need something other than `refresh`ing.  A resource broadcasts an event whenever Puppet changes its state in any way.  This causes resources receiving the event to refresh.  No information is conveyed about the nature or extent of the changes that caused the event to be broadcast, so there is no distinguishing between creation and other kinds of changes.

If indeed you have work that you want performed only upon creation of an instance of your custom resource, then the best thing to do would probably be to integrate that into the resource instead of trying to define it via a separate one.